# Content in model of a Component link returns null in Java + DXA

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I have a Schema with a Component link. The linked Component is a content of RTF fields. I have a Schema type`OnlineForm` (rootname: OnlineForm) and schema field `webMessage` is the Component link field type `webMessage` (xmlName: webMessage) is a Component link of multiple values of `General Page Content` (rootname: GeneralPageContent) Schema type `General Page Content` is a Schema containing a field `fullPageContent` (which is embedded Schema of Paragraph5Level (rootname:Paragraph5Level) and so on. It will be more clearer with the model.

1. OnlineForm:

   ```
   @SemanticEntity(entityName = "OnlineForm", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "of")
   public class OnlineForm extends AbstractEntityModel {

       @SemanticProperty("of:webMessage"),
       private GeneralPageContent webMessage;
   }
   ```
2. GeneralPageContent

   ```
   @SemanticEntity(entityName = "GeneralPageContent", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "gp")
   public class GeneralPageContent extends AbstractEntityModel {

       @SemanticProperty("gp:fullPageContent")
       @JsonProperty("FullPageContent")
       private List<Paragraph5Level> fullPageContent;
   }
   ```
3. Paragraph5Level

   ```
   @SemanticEntity(entityName = "Paragraph5Level", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "pl") 
   public class Paragraph5Level  extends AbstractEntityModel {

       @SemanticProperty("pl:heading")
       @JsonProperty("Heading")
       private String heading;

       @SemanticProperty("pl:paraContent")
       @JsonProperty("ParaContent")
       private List<RichText> paraContent;

       @SemanticProperty("pl:subParagraph")
       @JsonProperty("SubParagraph")
       private List<SubParagraphLevel2> subParagraph;
   }
   ```

When I preview the Component, I can see the Component link as seen below. (See `webMessage` and `fullPageContent` below.

```
"title": "Feedback",
"adminEmailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
"webMessage": {
    "$type": "EntityModelData",
    "Id": "9425",
    "ComponentTemplate": {
        "Id": "169",
        "RevisionDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
     },
     "Folder": {
         "Id": "2163",
         "Title": "Web Messages"
     },
     "Content": {
         "fullPageContent": {
             "$type": "ContentModelData",
             "heading": "Your request has been received and a customer service representative will contact you shortly."
         }
     },
     "SchemaId": "416"
},
"formFields": { ...
```

But in the controller when I call `model.getWebMessage`, this returns nullPointerException.

Comment: Your question contains very little information to work with, I think you might get more answers if you **edit** your question and add some more details. Like what fields are used in the Schema and the source code of the Model. It would be beneficial if you can reduce this to only the relevant fields, so that others can create a similar setup and try to recreate the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for responding Bart. I have modified my question. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: What are the root element/type names of your CM Schemas?

Comment: Updated the question with root element names

Comment: I didn't see this error before. ERROR c.s.w.c.i.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl - Exception while getting field data for: private com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.GeneralPageContent com.sdl.dxa.modules.onlineforms.model.OnlineForm.webMessage
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.exceptions.FieldConverterException: Cannot convert a entity model 9425 to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.GeneralPageContent for semantic field webMessage
 at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:43)